# MySQL certain characters cause 'illegal mix of collations' error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, character-encoding, collation

I haven't specifically seen this issue before but

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '=' (SQL:

```
select `id` from `data` where `thing` = خ@gmail.com limit 1
```

I'm pretty sure خ@gmail.com is not a valid email address but I am not too sure why Laravel's DB functions passed this to my server. Shouldn't it be aware of the character set and collation of the database it's using? Is the right solution to change the character set and collation to UTF-8 so that this doesn't cause general errors on my MySQL server?

Is there any consensus of what the correct character set and collation should be?

Comment: Don't you need to encapsulate the value with quotations? `where 'thing' = 'خ@gmail.com'`

Comment: You should always use `utf8mb4`

Comment: Hi, I am using Laravel's DB:: and also that is just the output from the error message not the actual query that is being used. Laravel is handling the 'quotations'.

Comment: When Laravel outputs failed queries using prepared statements, it does not show the quotes around the values. Makes it hard to troubleshoot by copy/pasting the query into the command line, since you'll have to manually quote things.

Comment: Check the definition of the table/column. It should be utf8_unicode_ci, but it's probably set to latin1_swedish_ci.

Comment: @aynber  If it's `utf8` then `@gmail.com` raises the same error.

Comment: @Rain Ah, okay. Collations confuse me, I was just picking one from the error. :-D

Answer (score 0):

Both the connection and the column definition need to be `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or `utf8mb4`).  From the error message, I see that one of them is clearly `latin1`.

In Laravel's config:

In the file config/database.php: 'mysql' => [..., 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', ...]

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to discuss the table.

If you end up with gibberish, see [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

The clinking beer mugs () requires utf8mb4 instead of utf8.  (utf8mb4 is a superset of utf8.)